# Problem with Broyden update: Divide by a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, expectation, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I am implementing a maximum likelihood method (the EM algorithm) for which I'm using Broyden's method at each iteration. Here is the formula:

$\Delta A = \frac{(\Delta \theta - A \Delta\tilde{g})\Delta\theta^{T}A}{\Delta\theta^{T}A\Delta\tilde{g}} $

$A$ is a scalar or a matrix, so the denominator is a scalar unless $\Delta \theta$ and $\Delta \tilde{g}$ are matrices. In this case, I don't know what to do. Does anyone have experience with this form of Broyden's method? Do you take the norm of the denominator to avoid dividing by a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, $\Delta\theta$ and $\Delta\tilde g$ are column vectors with $n$ entries (so they are $n\times 1$ matrices) and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix.  Therefore, $\Delta\theta^T A$ is the product of a $1\times n$ matrix with a $n\times n$ matrix (notice the transpose on the $\Delta\theta$), so that the result is a $1\times n$ matrix, also known as a row vector.  From this, we see the denominator of your expression for $\Delta A$ is of the form $$(\Delta\theta^T A)\Delta \tilde g \sim (1\times n)*(n\times 1)$$
where $\sim$ is used to indicate the dimensions of the matrices.  The result is therefore $1\times 1$: a scalar.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sometimes they are column vectors, but there are also cases where they are matrices, and that is where I am stuck. I actually have another question-- Are you familiar with this formula? Do you know if the point is to add $\Delta A$ to $A$ after it is computed, and continue iterating this way?

Comment: Never mind, I just verified that adding $\Delta A$ to $A$ is the right step. Back to the original question, I guess I should just take the norm of the denominator.

Comment: Why would $\Delta\theta$ and $\Delta\tilde g$ be matrices?  I've seen Broyden's method before; it's a quasi-Newton iterative method to solve a system of nonlinear equations, $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=0$, for $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$.  The way it's presented, the $\Delta\theta$ and $\Delta\tilde g$ are always $m$-vectors.  Please provide more detail relevant to your problem.

Comment: I'm using Broyden's method to accelerate the EM algorithm. This is an iterative method that updates estimates for unknown parameters $\theta$ at each iteration. Because I'm using multivariate Gaussian mixtures, my unknown parameters are mixing coefficients (scalars), means (vectors), and covariance matrices. So when it comes to the covariance, $\Delta \theta$ and $\tilde{g}$ are at least 2x2 matrices. The method is (minimally) described in [this paper](http://www.quretec.com/u/vilo/edu/2003-04/DM_seminar_2003_II/ver1/P10/artiklid/JamshidianJennrich.pdf).